# How do I write test code for testing my exception handling code?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit4

I'm writing unit test for legacy Java code. Now I'm encountering a problem. Below is the `class A` I want to write test code for.

```
class A {

    public A(){

    }

    public void doSomething()throws DBException {
        try{
            //some code that might throw JDBCConnectionException 
        }catch(JDBCConnectionException e){
            notifyJDBCConnection()
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    private void notifyJDBCConnection(){
        //do notification stuff
    }
}
```

Now say if I need to test whether the method `notifyJDBCConnection()` has been executed when `JDBCConnectionException` is caught. What is the right way to approach this problem? Or should I just write a test for testing method `notifyJDBCConnection` is okay?

Comment: Why `notifyJDBCConnection` is public?  Is it called from another class?

Comment: @saka1029  Yes, I think you are right. It is only called from `class A` and shouldn't be `public`.

Comment: Thanks for the surprising accept ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*One* way of approaching this:

1. You put the responsibility of *handling* that exception into its own class.
2. Then you use *dependency injection* to provide an object of that new class to your class *A*.
3. Now you can be using a mocking framework such as EasyMock or Mokito to pass a **mocked** instance of that exception handler class into A.
4. Finally, you verify that your mocked object sees the expected calls.

That approach might look like "more work" on the surface, but it can lead to a better design - as you separate concerns; and by creating a special exception handler class, you can test **that** class by its own, too!

Answer (score 1):

I presume that `notifyJDBCConnection` will call some kind of notification framework, be it an email sender or otherwise.  If you mock that component using a framework like [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), you can verify that the appropriate calls to said component have been made.

Comment: Yes. So does it mean that I don't have to write test code to cover the logic from `try` block to `catch` block including the exception handling part? All I have to do is to use Mockito to test the notification component, right?

Comment: Well, you need to get it to call the notification method somehow.  Does it call a JDBC object that you can mock as well?

Comment: You mean `notifyJDBCConnection`? No, it is only in charge of sending messages to other components.

Comment: I mean that `doSomething` will make a JDBC call at some point.  Mock it to throw the exception and check that your mock notification component gets called.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Mockito and JUnit with the design suggested by GhostCat:

```
class A {
    private final JDBCConnectionNotifier notifier;

    public A(JDBCConnectionNotifier notifier){
        this.notifier = notifier;
    }

    public void doSomething()throws DBException {
        try{
            //some code that might throw JDBCConnectionException 
        }catch(JDBCConnectionException e){
            notifier.notifyJDBCConnection()
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   
}
```

So the test class wold be:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.*;

class ATest {
    @Test
    public void shouldCallNotifierOnJDBCConnectionException() throws Exception {
        JDBCConnectionNotifier notifier = mock(JDBCConnectionNotifier.class);
        A a = new A(notifier);

        a.doSomething();

        verify(notifier).notifyJDBCConnection();
    }
}
```